# How do I get this pandas array shape to match this numpy array shape?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like the converted panda array `px` to be the same shape and data type as the numpy array `nx`. How do I do that?

```
import pandas
import numpy

nx = numpy.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], numpy.float32)
print(nx.shape)
print(nx.dtype)

data = pandas.read_json('{"array": [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]}')
px = data['array'].to_numpy()
print(px.shape)
print(px.dtype)
```

Output:

```
(3, 2)
float32
(3,)
object
```

Comment: You creat `nx` as a (3,2) float array.  `data` is a DataFrame, 2d, but dtype may depend on the load.  `data['array']`, an frame column is a pandas `Series`.  Its data is 1d.  But it looks like it is object dtype with array elements.  `np.stack(px)` might work to create a 2d integer array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a suitable NumPy array from JSON data, you don't actually need Pandas at all, just NumPy and Python's own JSON module.

```py
import json
import numpy as np

data = json.loads('{"array": [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]}')['array']
# Data is now a list just like the one supplied to create nx in your
# example. It can be printed to verify.
print(f'{data = }\n')

array = np.array(data, np.float32)
print(array)
print(f'\n{array.shape = }\n')
print(f'{array.dtype = }')
```

Output:

```py
data = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]

[[1. 1.]
 [2. 2.]
 [3. 3.]]

array.shape = (3, 2)

array.dtype = dtype('float32')
```

Note: the `=` inside the [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) is a handy way to see the variable names in output, for debugging, but it was only added in Python 3.8. If you're using an earlier version, just remove the `=` and the values will still print just fine. (Or print the variables directly without f-strings.)

Answer (score 0):

`'{"array": [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]}'` is not a Compatible JSON strings that can be produced by to_json() with a corresponding orient value. [See Examples here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)
One solution can be loading the data as a dictionary as showed below

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nx = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]], np.float32)
print(nx.shape)
print(nx.dtype)

data_dict = json.loads('{"array": [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]}')
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict["array"], dtype=np.float32)
px = data.to_numpy()
print(px.shape)
print(px.dtype)
```

Output

```
(3, 2)
float32
(3, 2)
float32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [258]: data = pd.read_json('{"array": [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]}')
In [259]: data
Out[259]: 
    array
0  [1, 1]
1  [2, 2]
2  [3, 3]
```

With this construction, the `array` column contains objects.  Whether those are strings, lists or arrays is not obvious from the display.  But:

```
In [262]: data.to_numpy()
Out[262]: 
array([[list([1, 1])],
       [list([2, 2])],
       [list([3, 3])]], dtype=object)
```

A data frame is 2d (always).  This array is (3,1) shape, with list elements.

Selecting a column gives us a `Series`, a 1d object:

```
In [264]: data['array'].to_numpy()
Out[264]: array([list([1, 1]), list([2, 2]), list([3, 3])], dtype=object)
```

If the element lists are all the same size then `np.stack` can combine them:

```
In [265]: np.stack(_)
Out[265]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Another way:

```
In [266]: data['array'].to_list()
Out[266]: [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
In [267]: np.array(data['array'].to_list())
Out[267]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier to start from `numpy` and import into `pandas`.  `numpy` is deterministic.  Even after working with it for quite a while, `pandas` is not so deterministic.  You can achieve your goal by using the Python `json` decoder:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(json.loads('{"array": [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]}')['array'])
```

Comment: Why not show how to do so straight in NumPy with no Pandas, then? I was going to post it myself, but I don't want to step on your toes if you're mentioning it first.

Comment: He already has it in straight `numpy`.  That's the "before" in his "before and after" comparison.  In fact, all one has to do is replace `pd.DataFrame` with `np.array` in my example, and it magically works.

Comment: More or less, I suppose. It's just that the final product of this is an int64 Pandas dataframe, rather than a float32 NumPy array like they're asking about.

Comment: This is fake data.  One presumes that his real data has floats.